# Cluster management

Tags: 18.04, cluster

Is there any tool or way to get the hardware and storage details of every computer within a connected network ?
I am able to view only list of connected computers within a network.
But I also want to know the hardware and storage details.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have SSH access and Python installed on all of them?

Comment: @Yaron. Yes Sir

Comment: Have you considered Ansible? It's a very good orchestration tool.

Comment: @Yaron I have not tried it yet. Can you share me proper installation link ? It will be very helpful. Thanks :-)

Comment: `sudo apt install ansible`, that's the easy part, the rest is learning how to use it :)

Comment: @Yaron Thanks a lot. I'll surely try it. Thanks a lot :-)